# Closing application and notifying renderer process

Tags: electron

I have an Electron application that needs to save some data when it's closed by the user (e.g. just after the user clicked on the "Close" button).

The data is available at the renderer process, so it should be notified before the application dies.

The [Electron API for Browser Window](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.0/api/browser-window/) mentions a `close` method, but it seems this is done by the main process, not the renderer one (if I'm not mistaken).

I tried using `WebContents.send` from the main process to notify the renderer process, but it seems that, because the message is asynchronous, the application is closed before the renderer process has the time to actually perform the operations.

Answer (score 9):

You can just use the normal [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) or [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) events in the renderer process:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
  // store data etc.
})
```

Answer (score 7):

So far, the simplest solution that worked for me consists in doing the following:

1. On the main process, the [BrowserWindow](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/browser-window/) listens on the `close` event, and when it happens, it sends a message via [webContents](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/web-contents/) to the renderer process. It also prevents the application from being immediately closed by calling [`event.preventDefault()`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/browser-window/#event-close);
2. The renderer process is always [listening on IPC messages](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/ipc-renderer/) from the main process, then when it receives the `close` event notification, it saves its data, then sends the main process an IPC message (e.g. `closed`);
3. The main process has previously set a hook to listen to the renderer IPC messages ([`ipcMain.on`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/ipc-main/)), so when the `closed` message arrives, it finally closes the program (e.g. via [`app.quit()`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/app/)).

Note that, if I understood it correctly, calling `app.quit()` sends another `close` event to the BrowserWindow, so it will loop unless you prevent it somehow. I used a dirty hack (quit the *second* time the `close` event is called, without calling `event.preventDefault()`), but a better solution must exist.

Comment: For the 3rd step, to avoid triggering the `before-quit` and `will-quit messages`, one could use `app.exit(0)` instead

Answer (score 4):

**On the Main process:**

```js
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
    let status = 0;

    mainWindow.on('close', function (e) {
        if (status == 0) {
            if (mainWindow) {
                e.preventDefault();
            mainWindow.webContents.send('app-close');
        }
    }
})

ipc.on('closed', _ => {
    status = 1;
    mainWindow = null;
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
})
```

**On the renderer process:**

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

ipc.on('app-close', _ => {

    //do something here...

    ipc.send('closed');
});
```