# Electron - Event not registered on renderer

Tags: electron

I'm trying to save a file before (or after, all it matters is that it gets called) quitting.
To do that on the main process I would do:

```js
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // (save file)
    app.quit();
});
```

Although doing the same while on a renderer process, wouldn't give you an error, but wouldn't work / ever get called.

Here's how my renderer is like:

```js
const app = require('electron').remote.app;
const fs = require('fs');

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // Never gets called
    fs.writeFile('test.txt', 'Something');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an way on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44709146/9124836)

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', event => {
    fs.writeFile('test.txt', 'Something');
});
```