# How to get data from renderer process on window close?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I am registering the close-event from the BrowserWindow in the MainProcess:

```js
mainWindow.on('close', function (event: Event) {
    // get window.modelIsDirty from renderer-process and when it is true, show the dialog.
    const choice = require('electron').dialog.showMessageBoxSync(this,
        {
            type: 'question',
            buttons: ['Yes', 'No', 'Cancel'],
            title: 'Closing',
            message: 'Do you want to save changes?'
        });
        
    if (choice === 1) {
          
    } else if (choice === 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here I want to check, if my model is dirty and then ask the question for saving. The dirty-value is saved in the renderer-process as a property in the window-object.

I am searching for a way to access the renderer process and read the value if my model is dirty. I need it for deciding when to show the message in the close-event.

Comment: I've been playing around with possible solutions for a couple of hours now without success. It always boils down to not having main -> render -> main promise functionality. Does your `dirty` flag need to be kept in the render process or **could** it be moved to the main process? I suspect having a ‘model’ in the render process means you are using some type of framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your `modelIsDirty` flag in your render process presents some issues which would be circumvented if it were to be kept in the main process. That aside, it took some time to come up with a way to implement such a requirement.

Whilst there are one or two Stackoverflow questions and answers that are similar to your problem (such as "[Closing application and notifying renderer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091378/closing-application-and-notifying-renderer-process)"), detecting window closure  and implementing a 'counting' or 'flag' system in the main process to keep track of when to close the window seemed sort of wrong to me. Additionally, this type of solution would not scale well when you wished to implement this type of functionality on one or more windows at the same time.

Initially, I tried to figure out how to implement `main` -> `render` -> `main` promise functionally, similar to [ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args,)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) but then it dawned on me that I did not need to try to squeeze all  of this logic into one function.

The process (shown below as a minimum reproducible example) has been tested on a single (main) window, a child window and a second window independent to that of the main window. All `dirtyData` returned to the main process is completely separate from other `dirtyData` windows. Separating the returned window data is achieved by receiving the data on different IPC channels. This would be the normal course of action in an Electron application anyway.

### The Process

First, we need to add an `input` event listener to every input element we wish to monitor. Following this, when the (`input`) event is triggered, check if the input value is different from that of when it was initialised on page load. If it is different, add a `beforeunload` listener to the `document` to detect when the user tried to close the window. If the user reverts the input value back to its initial value, then remove the `beforeunload` event listener **but only** if all other monitored inputs also match their initial values.

[image: Flowchart for change in input process]

Next, we need to listen for when the UI window is being closed by the user. If the window is being closed and the `beforeunload` event handler has been loaded, then we can intercept the window from closing. Once intercepted, we show the Confirmation Dialog and wait the user to make a choice about saving the dirty data.

- If the "Yes" button is clicked, request for the dirty data to be sent to the main process for saving and then close the window.
- If the "No" button is clicked, close the window without saving the dirty data.
- If the "Cancel" button (or "ESC" key) is clicked, close the dialog and leave the window open.

[image: Flowchart for handling of dirty data]

---

### `main.js` (main process)

Below is generic Electron startup code, apart from requiring the `dirty-data-main.js` (module) file.

```js
// Import required Electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Import required Application modules
require(nodePath.join(__dirname, './dirty-data-main'));

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

### `dirty-data-main.js` (main process)

Upon loading, the [`ipcMain.on(channel, listener)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener) methods are registered and waiting for action.

Next is the standard code for generating a [`dialog.showMessageBox([browserWindow, ]options)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options) dialog box.

Note that in the code block that executes when the "Yes" button is clicked (`result.response === 0`) we find the window that called the `dirtyData:showDialog` IPC channel by passing the `event` through from the IPC call to the `showDialog` function.

Within the function, we use `electronBrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender).webContents` to find the calling window, just prior to method chaining the [`contents.send(channel, ...args)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) method on the `dirtyData:requestData` channel.

As previously discussed, if the "No" button is clicked (`result.response === 1`), the window is closed without saving the dirty data.

Finally, clicking the "Cancel" button or "ESC" key just cancels the dialog and leaves the window open.

```js
// Import required Electron modules
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

electronIpcMain.on('dirtyData:showDialog', (event) => {
    console.log('Show save confirmation dialog');
    showDialog(event);
});

electronIpcMain.on('dirtyData:transferData', (event, data) => {
    console.log('Data from render process: ', data); // Save dirty data here
    console.log('Close the window');
    event.sender.close();
});

function showDialog(event) {
    let options = {
        type: 'question',
        title: 'Save Confirmation',
        message: 'Want to save your updates before closing?',
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No', 'Cancel']
    }

    electronDialog.showMessageBox(electronBrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender), options)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.response === 0) {
                console.log('Dialog "Yes" button pressed');
                console.log('Request data from render process');
                electronBrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender).webContents.send('dirtyData:requestData');
            } else if (result.response === 1) {
                console.log('Dialog "No" button pressed');
                console.log('Close the window');
                event.sender.close();
            } else {
                console.log('Dialog "Cancel" button or "ESC" key pressed');
                console.log("Don't close the window");
            }
        });
}
```

---

### `preload.js` (main process)

This `preload.js` script is purely channel based. It does not contain any concrete functions. Only whitelisted channel names that allows communication (with or without data) between the main process and render process(es).

The three necessary channel names for this example to work are:

- `dirtyData:showDialog`
- `dirtyData:transferData`
- `dirtyData:requestData`

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels
const ipc = {
    'channels': {
        // From render to main
        'send': [
            'dirtyData:showDialog',
            'dirtyData:transferData'
        ],
        // From main to render
        'receive': [
            'dirtyData:requestData'
        ],
        // From main to render (once)
        'receiveOnce': [],
        // From render to main and back again
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From render to main
        send: (channel, args) => {
            if (ipc.channels.send.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            if (ipc.channels.receive.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From main to render (once)
        receiveOnce: (channel, listener) => {
            if (ipc.channels.receiveOnce.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.once(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            if (ipc.channels.sendReceive.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And how to use its full functionality if interested.

```text
/**
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Main --> Render (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.receiveOnce('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Render --> Main (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.once('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await myPromise(data)
 *                  .then((result) => { return result; })
 *          });
 *
 * Main:    function myPromise(data) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }); }
 *
 */
```

---

### `index.html` (render process)

I based this file on it containing a `modelIsDirty` flag. In this instance, it is exported from the `dirty-data-render.js` module as a live binding.

The remaining code is to show the ``dirty-data-render.js` modules flexibility.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test - "Save Confirmation" Dialog On Window Close</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <label for="input1">Input 1: </label>
            <input type="text" id="input1" value="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="input2">Input 2: </label>
            <input type="text" id="input2" value="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="input3">Input 3: </label>
            <input type="text" id="input3" value="">
        </p>

        <hr>

        <label for="dirtyData">Dirty Data :</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="dirtyData" style="width: 2em; height: 2em;" disabled>
    </body>

    <script type="module" src="dirty-data-render.js"></script>

    <script type="module">
        import {monitor, modelIsDirty} from './dirty-data-render.js';

        monitor(['input1', 'input2', 'input3']);

        setInterval(() => {
            document.getElementById('dirtyData').checked = (modelIsDirty);
        }, 250);
    </script>
</html>
```

> PS: Try adding initial values to the inputs. The `dirty-data-render.js` script will detect these and treat them as the starting point of the inputs before their values change in the UI.

---

### `dirty-data-render.js` (render process)

Lastly, I made this file a module for maximum flexibility and reuse with other `html` render files, though it still needed some minor customisation to suit this minimum reproducible example.

As per usual, upon loading, the [`ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) method is registered and waiting for action (via the `preload.js` script).

The primary function of this file is `monitor` function. In the `index.html` file, these function arguments are the `input` id's to be "watch". It creates an initial copy of the input id's and their values, so the "current" inputs can be compared for any differences. If differences are found, then the window `beforeunload` event listener is registered and the `modelIsDirty` flag is set to `true`. If **all** current inputs match the initial input values, then the window `beforeunload` event listener is removed and the `modelIsDirty` flag is set to `false`.

Other functions within the file are support functions apart from the `beforeUnloadListener` function. This is the function that is called should the window `beforeunload` event listener be registered.

```js
'use strict';

let modelIsDirty = false;
let inputCopy = [];

window.ipcRenderer.receive('dirtyData:requestData', () => {
    console.log('Send data back to main process');
    window.ipcRenderer.send('dirtyData:transferData', dataSnapShot(inputCopy));
});

function monitor(input) {
    // Set input to outer scope (for use elsewhere)
    inputCopy = input;

    // Capture input ids and (initial) values
    let initialInput = dataSnapShot(input);

    // Add "input" event listeners to the inputs
    for (let i in input) {
        document.getElementById(input[i]).addEventListener('input', () => {
            if (document.getElementById(input[i]).value !== initialInput[input[i]]) {
                console.log('Add "beforeunload" event lister to window');
                window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener, {capture: true});
                modelIsDirty = true; // For use in UI
            } else if (! isDataDirty(input, initialInput)) {
                console.log('Remove "beforeunload" event lister from window');
                window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener, {capture: true});
                modelIsDirty = false; // For use in UI
            }
        });
    }
}

function dataSnapShot(input) {
    let result = {};

    for (let i in input) {
        result[input[i]] = document.getElementById(input[i]).value;
    }

    return result;
}

const beforeUnloadListener = function(event) {
    console.log('Prevent window from closing');
    event.returnValue = false;
    window.ipcRenderer.send('dirtyData:showDialog');
}

function isDataDirty(input, initialInput) {
    for (let i in input) {
        if (document.getElementById(input[i]).value !== initialInput[input[i]]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

export {monitor, modelIsDirty}
```

---

### In Summary

I know this answer may be a bit long-winded and quite detailed (if not overly complicated for your issue), but I am sure the above flowcharts really explain the thought, flow and logic required to implement such a re-usable feature.